# Ubuntu Phone Emulator and Developer Phone Release Date

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-phone

Will they release an emulator on which apps can be tested? If yes, which IDE will they choose? (eclipse, qt creator, mono, all of them?)

Also is there any way to get an Ubuntu Phone for developing purposes? I'd buy one for developing apps on it even if it does not run as slick as expected but I wouldn't buy an Android phone just to install Ubuntu afterwords.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator is released. Check this out: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/11/ubuntu-touch-emulator-released

Answer (score 6):

QtCreator is the recommended IDE.  An emulator is currently in the works and will hopefully be available shortly.  In the mean time, you can run your app as an Ubuntu desktop app.

There is no planned developer phone, but images of the Ubuntu for the phone will be made available for the Galaxy Nexus in the near future.

Comment: The truth we are crying! By having it in our hands!

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy Nexus images will be released in a month if im not mistaken. Im also looking forward to the SDK/Emu/DevPhone release so i can start making some stuff to.

Comment: Please quote the source of information.

Answer (score 1):

Touch developer preview of Ubuntu would be published on 21 February 2013, according to a [Canonical release](http://www.canonical.com/content/touch-developer-preview-ubuntu-be-published-21-february-2013). The touch developer preview of Ubuntu would be available to download from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TouchInstallProcess. Also to start developing Ubuntu Phone Apps you can install [Ubuntu SDK preview](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity Next maybe can be an option:
http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/

I also started a discussion here for talk about this possibility:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42259255#post42259255