# Testing Ubuntu mobile applications

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, testing, emulation

I'm currently reading a lot about the new Ubuntu mobile (phone) OS, and now I'm wondering if there is the possibility to test applications. I know that QtCreator is the recommended IDE and an emulator is currently in the works and will hopefully be available shortly (see [this Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235691/ubuntu-phone-emulator-and-developer-phone-release-date) by David Planella).

But this emulator is not available yet and the tip to test applications as an Ubuntu desktop app seems not to be the best solution to me. The QT qmlviewer also isn't able to emulate the interaction of the applications with the Ubuntu OS like integrating with the notification bar and the Ubuntu Dash.

So my question is, if there is an extension for the qmlviewer or if it will be a good idea to run Ubuntu mobile, which will be released at the end of this month, on a virtual host using VMware or VitrualBox, which will enable the developer to test the look and feel of his/her :-D application within the "real" OS.

**EDIT**: Found the QtQuick 2.0 [TestCase class](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtquick/qml-testcase.html) which could be used for test driven development using Unit Tests.

**EDIT**: The thread about [Running Ubuntu Touch on the Android Emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261427/ubuntu-touch-running-on-android-emulator) is also very interesting.

Comment: There is this very interesting thread on the Ubuntu Phone Mailing list on Launchpad that discuses this topic. Due to the time of you posting this question, there have been advances in the Emulator. Eventually, the SDK team will release an emulator. Until then, the is This. https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg02258.html

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-play-with-ubuntu-touch-apps-in-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Thanks for the link, but no, it is not. I was looking for a possibility to test applications, not to review the applications of others. Running the applications in a desktop environment might be enough for desktop applications like a calendar or todo list, but you are not able to test the hardware related apps like a snapshot or sms client app.

Comment: I don't see how you could do this without a device...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ubuntu Touch Emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator)

For More Details 
[Is there an Ubuntu Touch emulator or a way to install it in a VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259338/is-there-an-ubuntu-touch-emulator-or-a-way-to-install-it-in-a-vm)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only test applications if you install Ubuntu on your phone.  A list of supported phones can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) and install instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try 3 Ubuntu touch apps on desktop. Here is how to: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/ubuntu-touch-apps-arrive-on-ubuntu-desktop