# Ubuntu Touch running on Android Emulator

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch

As Ubuntu Touch has an underlying Android/CyanogenMod Layer, I would like to ask if it's possible with reasonable effort to run Ubuntu on the Android Emulator which is part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/259338/is-there-an-ubuntu-touch-emulator-or-a-way-to-install-it-in-a-vm

Comment: @slashcrack: I saw that question and I guess I can definitely say that there is no emulator available yet. For that reason I wanted to find people who can give some information how easy it is actually to create an image e.g. and configure the existing Android Emulator. So I wouldn't consider this as a duplicate. I would in fact be happy to get some details about the possibility to create a new emulator. That would be exciting to hear about.

Comment: There is now an emulator, so this question is a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several resources how to run CyanogenMod on the Android Emulator. So this is definitely possible and the effort seems to be reasonable. Also there are many people already working on solutions how to port the existing Ubuntu Touch to other real devices. In the same way would be a port to the Android Emulator work as well.

Resources:

[Android SDK Emulator Compile CyanogenMod (Linux)](https://gist.github.com/SunRain/1681491)

[Build CyanogenMod for use on the Android Emulator](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Envsetup_help#lunch)

[Touch Developer Preview - Porting Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you would not be able to run Ubuntu Touch on the Android Emulator. The Android Emulator emulates the Davlik VM which is not Part of the modified CyanogenMod Kernel, which is used for the Ubuntu Touch OS. But there are several other options to test your applications.

1. You could use qmlscene (a smart qt qml viewer).
2. You could test on a Smartphone like the HTC Desire (bravo) which 
   you could buy for about 30€.
3. If you are a windows user you could run Ubuntu in a VM.
4. You could buy a developer board like the Odroid-U2 and port Ubuntu Touch OS for this
   device. A version of CyanogenMod 10.1 is available for it.

Comment: Note that the Android emulator in the SDK is a system image emulator; dalvik is user-mode code that runs within the emulated ARM or x86 system.So in theory you *ought* to be able to run the emulator... but no idea how difficult it would be to create a matching image.

Comment: Just remembered that I saw that the latest release of the Android Emulator, an option to run the program on an emulated nexus 7 environment. So maybe its not too hard to port the offical Ubuntu Phone image for the nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity Next maybe can be an option:
http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/

I also started a discussion here for talk about this possibility:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42259255#post42259255